# Got this Logical thinking questions

Tags: pattern, visual

for my school test. I got 54%/

Can someone help me to how to figure it out so in future I wont have trouble. I marked red which I think it doesn't fit the rule.

Can someone care to explain me this?

[image]

**Unedited Image :**

[image]

Comment: Can you add the unaltered image?

Comment: 2nd Image is unedited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer the image for following points:

1. Circle is odd one out.
2. It should be a cube with 5 objects.
3. all are straight lines while one should be dashed.
4. only here the lines intersect
5. solid shape instead of dotted borders
6. only here the smaller shape is inside the bigger shape
7. doesn't go with the sequence. It should be a circle.
8. only here the smaller shape is outside the bigger shape
9. doesn't go with the sequence. It should contain 5 dots.
10. only here there are two dashed lines
11. curves are intersecting
12. only here the smaller shape is inside the bigger shape
13. doesn't go with the sequence. It should be opposite in direction.
14. doesn't go with the sequence.It should contain 4 shapes.
15. doesn't go with the sequence. It should be a straight vertical line.
16. doesn't go with the sequence. Should be solid shape not a curve.
17. position of dot doesn't go with the sequence. It should be at top left most position.
18. doesn't go with the sequence. It should contain either 4 or 2 shapes.
19. doesn't go with the sequence. It should be shaded in gray.
20. doesn't go with the sequence. It should contain two dots to fit in.

[image]

Comment: Why, though? The sequences for 18 and 20 don't make sense to me. What are the sequences?

Comment: 18: alternates even and odd. 20: merge of 1-2-3-4-5 with 4-3-2-1.

Comment: Certainly 13 should actually be the 4th arrow? It's the same as 17 with four directions instead of eight....

Comment: @Will Oh yes I agree. That is an alternative answer(with better explanation I must say) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I will refer to them as A through I, where A is the first shape, B is the second, and so on.

Row 1:

> A is the only non-triangle.

Row 2:

> Each one adds or subtracts a shape except E.

Row 3:

> All have one broken line except B.

Row 4:

> G is the only one where there is an intersection.

Row 5:

> There are two options here: H is the only non-dotted one, and G is the only concave one.

Row 6:

> I is the only one where a shape is inside another shape.

Row 7:

> F breaks the alternating circle/square pattern.

Row 8:

> All contain one shape inside the other except for G.

Row 9:

> This is the exact same as row 2.

Row 10:

> All have one broken line except F.

Row 11:

> Only I has an intersection.

Row 12:

> All contain one shape inside the other except for E.

Row 13:

> If D were turned upside down, then the arrow would be rotating a quarter turn every step.

Row 14:

> D can't count.

Row 15:

> The row repeats `| + ×` except for G.

Row 16:

> It alternates between shapes and lines except for C.

Row 17:

> If C were turned upside down, then the dot would be moving a space clockwise every step.

Row 18:

> 

Row 19:

> The colors repeat white-gray-black except for E.

Row 20:

> 